# Obtain date difference based on different columns id

Tags: mysql

I have an `employee` database that shows me peer week the couple of employees who work together,
for the next week i need to know how many rest days that employee had...

- Every employee had an unique ID
- Depending of the week you work as Employee1 or Employee2
- The calculations of the rest days starts in week 2 so 9999 is the default number if there is no restDay

so, let's take for example the employee with id 2, in the week 1 he works as emp2, but the next week he works as emp1. I need to obtain the rest days, which in this case it will be for the emp1...

the columns in my db are

```
 1. id
 2. employee1
 3. employee2
 4. week
 5. emp1_restDay
 6. emp2_restDay
 7. date_time
```

[db example](http://i61.tinypic.com/28uiss5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Bad data structure, but I guess you have to deal with it.  You need to get one column per employee, which you can do using `union all`:

```
select employee, sum(restDay)
from ((select id, week, employee1 as employee, emp1_restDay as restDay, datetime
       from table t
      ) union all
      (select id, week, employee2 as employee, emp2_restDay as restDay, datetime
       from table t
      )
     ) t
group by employee;
```